# How to create, add custom properties to and fire custom events in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, custom-event

## Scenario:

While browsing the web for a solution to Javascript Custom Events, I couldn't find any practical examples, and even the MDN resource is really limited.

I am trying to rebuild [paperjs' onMouseDrag event](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool/#onmousedrag). My intended use is for a paint-like web-application.

The onMouseDrag event fires when:

- The left mouse button is down
- The mouse is moving

## Goal:

The goal here is *not* to have a working `onMouseDrag` event. The goal is to have a clear **explanation** and **example** of how to create a `CustomEvent`. The `onMouseDrag` event is only there as an example.

## Requirements:

1. The answer should be in [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/) or plain js. (*no jQuery or any other library)*
2. The answer should use `new CustomEvent()` or `new Event()`, not any of the deprecated methods.
3. When mousedrag gets called, the event argument passed should be the **same** event argument which mousemove receives.

## Code:

I've tried the following

```
var onMouseDrag = new CustomEvent('mousedrag'),
    elem = document.getElementById('element'),
    mousedown = false;

elem.addEventListener('mousedrag', function (event) {
    // The event argument passed should be 
    // the same event as the event passed by any other mouse event.

    // Do something while the mouse is being dragged.
});

elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    mousedown = true;
});

elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    mousedown = false;
});

elem.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (mousedown) {
        elem.dispatchEvent('mousedrag');
        // Pass the event variable to the dispatched mousedrag.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it, but you have dispatch the original event you created, not the string

```
var onMouseDrag = new CustomEvent('mousedrag'),
    elem = document.getElementById('element'),
    mousedown = false;

elem.addEventListener('mousedrag', function (event) {
    console.log(event)
});

elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    mousedown = true;
});

elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    mousedown = false;
});

elem.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (mousedown) 
        elem.dispatchEvent(onMouseDrag);
});
```

**EDIT:**

It seems you can just add properties to the event object

```
var onMouseDrag = new CustomEvent('mousedrag'),
    elem = document.getElementById('element'),
    mousedown = false;

elem.addEventListener('mousedrag', function (event) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'point';
    div.style.top = (event.clientY-71) + 'px';
    div.style.left = (event.clientX-41) + 'px';
    elem.appendChild(div);
});

elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    mousedown = true;
});

elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    mousedown = false;
});

elem.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (mousedown)  {
        onMouseDrag.clientX = event.clientX;
        onMouseDrag.clientY = event.clientY;
        elem.dispatchEvent(onMouseDrag);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCY75/3/)

Comment: I'm still not sure how to pass custom data at event-dispatch time. (When the event is being dispatched, the mousedrag listener should receive the original event)

`elem.addEventListener('mousedrag', function (event) {
    var x = event.offsetX,
        y = event.offsetY;

    console.log(x, y); // logs undefined, undefined
});`

Comment: That's because only the native mouse events have the pointers position, you'll have to add those to the event. Give me a sec to look at it ?

Answer (score 2):

To add more data to the event object, the CustomEvent interface exists and the detail property can be used to pass custom data.
For example, the event could be created as follows:

`const event = new CustomEvent('build', { detail: elem.dataset.time });`
This will then allow you to access the additional data in the event listener:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log('The time is: ' + e.detail);
}
```